# How to correctly configure Gmail to send E-mail with Django. The official configuration does not work for me

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

I am preparing an online portfolio made with Django and one of the features is a form with which you can contact me via E-mail. To verify that this functionality worked correctly, I have been testing it with MailTrap and it works perfectly, now for the production version I want the E-mails to reach my Gmail mail, but despite the fact that in theory I have followed all the steps, no I get it to work, it only worked for me with MailTrap.

**In my Gmail account I already activated two-step verification and created a specific password for the application.** The lower security option apparently does not exist since May of this year.

This is the configuration of my Settings.py:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_USER = "my-e-mail@gmail.com"
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'smbumqjiurmqrywn'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

This password is just an example, it is just to show how it is set.

And this is the method to send the E-mail. I am using EmailMessage but with send_mail the result is the same:

```
def contact(request):
contact_form = ContactForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    contact_form = ContactForm(data = request.POST)

    if contact_form.is_valid():
        name = request.POST.get('name', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        content = request.POST.get('content', '')

        # Send E-mail.
        email = EmailMessage(
            'New message from {} <{}>'.format(name, email),
            'From {} <{}>\n\nWrote:\n\n{}'.format(name, email, content),
            email,
            [settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER]
        )
        
        email.send()
        
return render(request, 'core/contact.html', {'form' : contact_form})
```

As I said, if I change the credentials in Settings.py to MailTrap it works without changing anything else, but Gmail doesn't and I don't know where the problem could be.

At the end of the method, I put the email.send() inside a try to know more easily when it failed and when it didn't, with the Gmail configuration it always enters the except.

I have entered the section where the specific passwords are created in my Gmail account several times after trying to send an E-mail and the part where it says "Last use" is empty, I do not know if it is related to the problem.

Traceback:

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/contact-me/

Django Version: 3.2.7
Python Version: 3.9.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'core',
 'portfolio.apps.PortfolioConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC CASE Gerardo\OneDrive\Documents\Proyectos\Python\webpersonal\core\views.py", line 34, in contact
    email.send()
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py", line 67, in open
    self.connection.starttls(keyfile=self.ssl_keyfile, certfile=self.ssl_certfile)
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 764, in starttls
    self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 607, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
    (code, resp) = self.helo()
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 436, in helo
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "C:\Python\Python39\lib\smtplib.py", line 400, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")

Exception Type: SMTPServerDisconnected at /contact-me/
Exception Value: Connection unexpectedly closed
```

Comment: Don't use `except` without specifing `Exception`. Do you know why it fails? Errors tell A LOT of important information. Delete `try/except` and share the error. I think you don't use 3rd party password that you have to create for every app.

Comment: @NixonSparrow I have added new info and I have deleted the try except. It has thrown me an SMTPServerDisconnected. Tell me if you need something more. Thanks.

Comment: Traceback would be also useful. Are you using the main password for google account or have you created that 3rd party password?

Comment: @NixonSparrow Sorry for the delay. I am using a generated key for third party applications. I have edited the post again and I have put the traceback and other info.

Comment: It's probably some setting in Google directly. Here everything looks ok. By the way, traceback is below the part from the picture you have shared.

Comment: @NixonSparrow Now you should be able to see the changes I've made.

Comment: No entiendo en español ;) Stack overflow is english only. Just try different options.

Comment: @NixonSparrow Basically that's Google's security setting to show you that it had indeed created the third party key, I put it in just for that. The traceback is the important thing.

Comment: Traceback gives only one information - it's most likely something with Google settings. I can't help you more.